# Which strategy makes more sense in this jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making a jQuery plugin that displays alerts on the page. The plugin itself inserts the alert markup into the DOM. Since the jQuery way is to make everything return `this` to maintain chaining, I've run into an interesting issue I'd like feedback on. I'm trying to decide between the following two options.

Option One:

```
$("#content").alert('prepend', {type:'error', message:'This is an error'})
```

This looks pretty simple. An alert is prepended to the beginning of the `#content` DOM element. The problem is that it's unclear what is returned. It would make sense to return the alert element that was just created, but that kind of goes against the jQuery way.

Option Two:

```
$("<div>").alert({type:'error', message:'This is an error'}).prependTo("#content")
```

This way seems less clear and less intuitive, but it's more inline with the jQuery way of doing things, and it's clear what element is going to be returned.

**So which options would you choose?** My concern is that most users may not know that you can do `$('<div>')` to create a new element. On the other hand, I don't know of any well-known projects whose jQuery plugin methods return elements other than the elements they're invoked on, but perhaps there are. Thoughts?

Comment: Personally I like option two better, but that's just my (uninformed) opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just put it in the jQuery namespace (instead of on its prototype):

```
$.alert({type:'error', message:'This is an error'}).prependTo("#content");
```

---

In addition, you might consider asking for a selector/DOM node/jQuery object, instead of having the user prepend it themselves:

```
$.alert({
    parent: '#content', // or $('#content') or document.getElementById('content')
    type: 'error',
    message: 'This is an error'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually contemplating the idea using `$.alert` in conjunction with `$.fn.alert`. Do you know of any documentation on the pros vs. cons of this? I know the difference between the two in regular JavaScript, but I don't see `$.method` very often in jQuery plugins so it seems like it might be frowned upon. Any ideas?

Comment: @PhilipWalton - I don't know why you would say that. I've seen many plugins out in the wild which just work off the jQuery namespace. Here's one that's trying to do something similar to what you're doing: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: This repo ended up being really helpful for me in this situation: https://github.com/zenorocha/jquery-plugin-patterns

Answer (score 0):

If your alert system is meant to be a popup-like or modal-like system, the user shouldn't have to specify a container. However, you can allow him to pass a container to insert your alertbox in:

```
$.alert({
  type: 'error',
  message: 'This is an error',
  container: $(...) // Optional
});
```

It would return your plugin instance, or the alert container.

Answer (score 0):

No, jQuery does not always return `this`. Chainability means only that you should return the instance itself if there's no result of your method.

For example, the `clone()` returns a new jQuery instance too; so there's nothing wrong with it. If you say "it's unclear", just document it, or rename the method to e.g. "`$.fn.getAlert`".

Yet, you must choose the signature of your method. The first option is like having a mandatory parameter for the container. If you like to make it optional, you might make the alert system a static method: `$.createAlert(...)` with an optional parameter.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. The `clone` method is specifically designed to return something else (if it hadn't, where would the cloned element go). To me, `clone` is equivalent to `.val()`: it obviously isn't returning the original element, since the only purpose of the method is to return some other value.